# Point cloud clustering based on similarity in less than $O(n^2)$

Tags: algorithms, clustering

not sure if this is the right place to ask this but here it goes.

Let's assume I have some 2D points dataset consisting of facial landmarks, and I want to cluster these based on similarity so that I can refer to a notion of "prototype" of a facial expression.

As a measure between one point set and another I could be using a sum of euclidean distances.

Is there a way to obtain a set of prototypes without passing through the landmarks $O(n^2)$ times?

To better explain what I'm thinking, let's say I'm processing a video frame by frame.

I start with the landmarks of the first frame, and I put it in my list of prototypes because I have no other reference.

Following this, for each subsequent frame, I compare it with the first "prototype" and if it's below a certain similarity threshold I assume it's not unique enough and skip it, and so until I find one set of landmarks that are dissimilar enough, so now I have two "prototypes".

From this point onward, I need to do the similarity check with two "prototypes", and so on.

Another caveat is that I would also like to be able to store the "prototype" that the current frame matches the most.

I will also need to do a second pass through a second clip for a similar matching with the "prototypes" identified in the first pass.

Is there a more efficient way to do this, other than the naive approach?